# If a quantum error correcting code can correct every single-qubit $X$ and $Z$ error, can it also correct every single-qubit $Y$ error?

Tags: error-correction

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a given arbitrary $n$ qubit quantum error correcting code which can correct any single qubit $X$ error and any single qubit $Z$ error, i.e., $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ & $\{Z_i\}_{i=1}^n $.

Should this code also be able to correct $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ errors?

I agree that $\mathcal{C}$ can correct any linear combination, $a X_i + b Z_j$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, and can also detect any $X_iZ_j$ or $Z_iX_j$ errors. But should it always be able to correct $Y_i$ errors?

---

I can convince myself that this holds true for some stabilizer codes, but what about any arbitrary code? The discussion [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26846/if-a-quantum-error-correcting-code-corrects-both-x-and-z-errors-will-it-be) is not satisfactory enough for me. How can we formally approach this?

One approach I could think of is using the Knill-Laflamme theorem. Let $E$ be the set of correctable errors of $\mathcal{C}$ (Kraus operator for correctable noise channel). $$E =\{X_1, X_2 , \cdots, X_n, Z_1, Z_2, \cdots, Z_n\}  \equiv \{E_\alpha\}\,.\tag{1}$$

Then, from the Knill-Laflamme theorem, we know that
$$ P E_\alpha^{\dagger}E_\beta P = \gamma_{\alpha \beta} P \tag{2} $$
holds true, where $[\gamma]$ is hermitian and $P$ is the projector on the codespace of $\mathcal{C}$.

But what can we conclude about the following, $\forall i,j,\alpha$?

$P Y_i E_\alpha P =\, ? \tag{3.1}$
$P E_\alpha^{\dagger} Y_j P=\, ?\tag{3.2}$
$P Y_i Y_j P=\, ? \tag{3.3}$

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question. But take the '$Y$ repetition code' on $n$ qubits where the stabilizer generators are $S_i=Y_i Y_{i+1}$. This is a distance 1 quantum code since a single $Y$ is a logical operator but all up to $n-1$ purely $X$ and $Z$ errors are detected errors.

Comment: @JonasAnderson Thank you for your comment. The question I am asking is, if a code can correct any one qubit $X$ error and also one qubit $Z$ error, does this imply that the code should also have the ability to correct any one qubit $Y$ error? If so, how can we prove that rigorously?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR:** No. The ability to correct single-qubit $X$ and $Z$ errors does not imply the ability to correct single-qubit $Y$ errors.

### Stabilizer generators

Consider the $[\![7,3]\!]$ code with stabilizer group $S$ generated by
$$
\begin{align}
G_0&=IIIYYYY\\
G_1&=IYYIIYY\\
G_2&=YIYIYIY\\
G_3&=XXXXXXX.
\end{align}
$$
This is like the Steane code where the $X$ and $Z$ sectors have been replaced with the $Y$ sector and where $X^{\otimes 7}$ has been introduced to tell $X$ and $Z$ errors apart. The maneuver adds two logical qubits, but will turn out to reduce the code distance.

Any single-qubit $X$ and $Z$ error gives rise to a syndrome $g_3g_2g_1g_0$ where the three least significant bits identify the affected qubit and the most significant bit discerns between $X$ and $Z$. Thus, there is a simple and effective recovery procedure for these errors.

On the other hand, every single-qubit $Y$ error gives rise to the same syndrome $1000$. If there is degeneracy in the code, this information could perhaps be sufficient for successful diagnostics and recovery. Not here. Logical operators live in $N(S)\setminus S$, but $N(S)$ contains many weight-two operators while $S$ contains none. Therefore, the code has distance two. But then some single-qubit errors cannot be corrected. Since all single-qubit $X$ and $Z$ errors can be corrected, then some single-qubit $Y$ errors can't be.

Thus, we have a stabilizer code that corrects all single-qubit $X$ and $Z$ errors but fails to correct some single-qubit $Y$ errors.

### Logical operators

Another, less rigorous, but perhaps more pedagogical way to see this is to find a viable set of logical operators, such as
$$
\begin{align}
\overline{X}_1&=IIIXXXX\\
\overline{Z}_1&=IIYIIIY\\
\overline{X}_2&=IXXIIXX\\
\overline{Z}_2&=IIIIYIY\\
\overline{X}_3&=XIXIXIX\\
\overline{Z}_3&=IIIIIYY.
\end{align}
$$
Clearly, certain pairs of single-qubit $Y$ errors combine to give a logical operator. But all such errors yield the same syndrome, so no decoder can tell them apart. However, failure to tell them apart is now a logical error.

Once again, we conclude that our stabilizer code corrects all single-qubit $X$ and $Z$ errors but fails to correct some single-qubit $Y$ errors.

### Intuition

This is a special case of a general fact: errors corrected by a quantum error correcting code form a vector space, but not necessarily an algebra. Less abstractly, if $E_1$ and $E_2$ can be corrected, then so can $aE_1+bE_2$, but not necessarily $E_1E_2$. The general case is of course easy to see because $E_1E_2$ may have a higher weight than $E_1$ and $E_2$.

The code above demonstrates that this fact is deeper than the simple observation about weight. Instead of considering the weight one should consider what gives rise to syndrome information. Non-trivial syndrome arises when an error operator and a check operator anticommute. However, if both $E_1$ and $E_2$ anticommute with a check operator $G$ then $E_1E_2$ commutes with $G$. This may deny the decoder useful syndrome information preventing $E_1E_2$ from being correctly diagnosed.